# How to describe this type of laughing?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, adjectives

How to describe myself laughing heartily (at anything funny/hilarious, not offensive one), need a while stopping it, with my body bending forward a little bit(or more)?

This is my trying: "I'm laughing like a shrimp."(The shape alike)

Am I saying this the right way? If you know a better one please let me know!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this a smoothly one?

That sentence is not used in English. We'd say, "Is this idiomatical?" Or, "Am I saying this the right way?"

**bent over with laughter**

**doubled over in laughter**

AmE native speakers use these. *Doubled over* or *bent over* need the word laughter or a context to describe what is happening in English. Otherwise one could be *doubled over* in pain or grief.

Comment: Sorry, I originally want to said "Does this sentence read smoothly?". And... Is this idiomatical? / Am I saying this the right way?

Comment: You can still say it. You can edit your question at anytime. It's comments that have a set time allowance. I am assuming that you are wanting to learn so, "I originally **want** to **said**", should read, "I originally **wanted** to **say,**". I hope I am not offending you by correcting you. I completely understood what you meant.

Comment: Never mind. You're helping me, I'm very grateful for you.

Answer (score -4):

There is a verb in English which may be exactly what you're looking for: [*neigh*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neigh).

Example from the dictionary:

> They **neighed** dutifully at jokes they did not understand.

Comment: If the OP wants to describe the sounds of laughter then: cackle, chortle,crow,guffaw or sputtered or barked with laughter

Comment: It means "to make a sound like neighing", but it doesn't specifically refer to laughter, and I have never heard anyone use in connection with laughing.

Comment: Hope you would not be upset by people's down votes. And here is a good news: I did try yours like "I'm always neighing when you acting." and get a positive reply "Haha, thanks!" today!